# Updating knockout variable value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the below model

```
var CountryScopeVM = function (data, root) {
    CountryScopeVM.call(this, data);
    var self = this;
    this.isSelected = ko.observable();
    this.centralImpLowHeadCount = ko.observable();
    this.load(data);   
    }
};
 this.countryScopes = ko.observableList(CountryScopeVM, data.countryScopes, this);
```

And I have the below code which gets called when a checkbox is selected. What I am trying to do here is have all the  centralImpLowHeadCount inside the countryscope array get updated when the main checkbox is checked but it is not updating and I don't see the change in the UI.

```
 selectAllLOWImplementation: function (data, event) {
        var select = $(event.target).is(':checked');
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(model.countryScopes() || [], function (countryScope) {
            countryScope().centralImpLowHeadCount == select;
        });
        return true;
    }
```

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: hasSelectedLOWImplementation, click: selectAllLOWImplementation" />


 <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: centralImpLowHeadCount, enable: isOn"  /></td>
```

Comment: I don't think ko.observableList is a thing it is observableArray http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: You're also presumably trying to assign a value using a comparison operator. `countryScope().centralImpLowHeadCount == select;` should probably be `countryScope().centralImpLowHeadCount(select);`

Comment: I tried this countryScope().centralImpLowHeadCount(select); but I am getting an error Javascript runtime error : function expected

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis after `countryScope()`. It doesn't appear to be an observable in the code you've posted.